# File upload button is still not working in Cordova / Phonegap Project

Tags: javascript, function, cordova, upload

Iam unable to upload pictures to a webserver with PHP backend.
My cordova camera script is able to taking the picture and show the picture in small size. But it is not able to upload an image. I dont no why. I call the function photoUpload(); and set the a onClick-event in the button like

```
<button class="camera-control" onclick="photoUpload();">UPLOAD</button>
```

Here is my JavaScript, whats wrong with it?

```
var pictureSource;
var destinationType;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

function clearCache() {
    navigator.camera.cleanup();
}

var retries = 0;
function onCapturePhoto(fileURI) {
    $("#cameraPic").attr("src", fileURI);
    var win = function (r) {
        clearCache();
        retries = 0;
        navigator.notification.alert(
        '',
        onCapturePhoto,
        'Der Upload wurde abgeschlossen',
        'OK');
        console.log(r);
    }

    var fail = function (error) {
        navigator.notification.alert(
        'Bitte versuchen Sie es noch einmal.',
        onCapturePhoto,
        'Ein unerwarteter Fehler ist aufgetreten',
        'OK');
        console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
        console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
        if (retries == 0) {
            retries ++
            setTimeout(function() {
                onCapturePhoto(fileURI)
            }, 1000)
        } else {
            retries = 0;
            clearCache();
            alert('Fehler!');
        }
    }

    function photoUpload() {
    var fileURI = $("#cameraPic").attr("src");
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    var params = new Object();
    params.fileKey = "file";
    options.params = {}; // eig = params, if we need to send parameters to the server request


    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://xxxx/app/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
    }

}


function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onCapturePhoto, onFail, {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI
    });
}


function getPhoto(source) {
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: source });
    }

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? if it goes inside function upload photo?

Comment: In firebug i get this: ReferenceError: photoUpload is not defined <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: So check if your js file is loading from the server, and this is really your js file with your code and not default *.html file that server return.

Comment: No, my js code is included in my .html File.

Comment: @hossi, You had asked same question few days ago, did it help you what I suggested ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27155646/cordova-upload-image-not-working-after-taking-picutre/27165215#27165215

Answer (score 0):

Look your function photoUpload is located in the function onCapturePhoto! you need to move function photoUpload on the top level.

```
window.photoUpload = function() {
var fileURI = $("#cameraPic").attr("src");
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
options.chunkedMode = false;

var params = new Object();
params.fileKey = "file";
options.params = {}; // eig = params, if we need to send parameters to the server request


var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://xxxx/app/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
}
```

And the better way to do it like:

```
<button class="camera-control" id="photoUploadButton;">UPLOAD</button>

document.getElementById("photoUploadButton").addEventListener("click", photoUpload);
```

Comment: I did it in this way, but the upload-Button has still no function.