# Uploading Picture From PhoneGap Cordova App

Tags: php, android, cordova, mime

Trying to get photo to upload but can't get the file data to the server.  The app brings up the camera and does a POST to the server but there is never any file uploaded.

I've created the simplest app I could to test this at https://github.com/dustinb/Camera/blob/master/index.html.  When the upload happens there is only 452 bytes sent to the server.

```
73.3.252.133 - - [04/Dec/2014:23:55:11 +0000] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 200 452 "-" "Dalvik/1.4.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; ADR6400L Build/GRJ22)"
```

I've looked a numerous examples of this and can't see anything different than what I have. I'm using build.phonegap.com to build and install

Edit: Using tcpdump I can see the data is getting to the server just nothing in $_POST or $_FILES variables in PHP

```
    0x0030:  150c 34c5 504f 5354 202f 7570 6c6f 6164  ..4.POST./upload
    0x0040:  2048 5454 502f 312e 310d 0a43 6f6e 7465  .HTTP/1.1..Conte
    0x0050:  6e74 2d54 7970 653a 206d 756c 7469 7061  nt-Type:.multipa
    0x0060:  7274 2f66 6f72 6d2d 6461 7461 3b20 626f  rt/form-data;.bo
    0x0070:  756e 6461 7279 3d2b 2b2b 2b2b 0d0a 5573  undary=+++++..Us
    0x0080:  6572 2d41 6765 6e74 3a20 4461 6c76 696b  er-Agent:.Dalvik
    0x0090:  2f31 2e34 2e30 2028 4c69 6e75 783b 2055  /1.4.0.(Linux;.U
    0x00a0:  3b20 416e 6472 6f69 6420 322e 332e 343b  ;.Android.2.3.4;
    0x00b0:  2041 4452 3634 3030 4c20 4275 696c 642f  .ADR6400L.Build/
    0x00c0:  4752 4a32 3229 0d0a 486f 7374 3a20 7371  GRJ22)..Host:.sq
    0x00d0:  7561 7265 732e 726f 756e 6470 6f72 6368  uares.roundporch
    0x00e0:  2e63 6f6d 0d0a 436f 6e6e 6563 7469 6f6e  .com..Connection
    0x00f0:  3a20 4b65 6570 2d41 6c69 7665 0d0a 4163  :.Keep-Alive..Ac
    0x0100:  6365 7074 2d45 6e63 6f64 696e 673a 2067  cept-Encoding:.g
    0x0110:  7a69 700d 0a43 6f6e 7465 6e74 2d4c 656e  zip..Content-Len
    0x0120:  6774 683a 2032 3933 3530 0d0a 0d0a       gth:.29350....
    -- next packet --
    0x0000:  4500 05dc 617d 4000 3206 a8e9 4903 fc85  E...a}@.2...I...
    0x0010:  68cf 8a5d d68c 0050 aa2b ce30 13d2 95d7  h..]...P.+.0....
    0x0020:  8010 02da 80ec 0000 0101 080a 01be ac57  ...............W
    0x0030:  150c 34c5 ffd8 ffe1 0116 4578 6966 0000  ..4.......Exif..
    0x0040:  4949 2a00 0800 0000 0e00 3201 0200 1400  II*.......2.....
```

Seems the problem is the mime boundary with Content-Disposition and other headers is not being sent.  Can see in the dump after Content-Length is sent the JPEG data is immediately sent next with no mime boundary used.

Comment: Is your server up and able to receive data from app without any problem like firewall, proxy etc. Plus if you are using any Webservice to upload image, can you test it separately

Comment: your code is pretty correct and I used similar and it worked: see my example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27155646/cordova-upload-image-not-working-after-taking-picutre/27165215#27165215

Comment: Cann't you upload image without app - I mean if you create a test webapp to upload image and see the differences. In this way at least you will be sure that server/webservice is working fine and now issue is with the mobile app (code)...This is just an idea to separate the issues

Comment: Looking at tcpdump I see the data being upload (updated question) but there is not $_POST or $_FILES data.  The same /upload script works for standard web browser upload.  Something with the server side or how phone gap is encoding the POST data is not cooperating.

Comment: One thing I noticed is the multipart boundary shows as +++++.. but the boundary is never used, FileTransfer just sends the raw jpeg data in the body of the request with no boundary information.  When I do the same dump using the standard web upload form the request has the mime boundary with name, filename headers then sends the image data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was using the wrong File Transfer plugin. Not sure where I found the other plugin or why it was used but doesn't work

```
-    <gap:plugin name="com.chanthu.evri.gcs-file-transfer" version="1.0.0" />
+    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-trasfer" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to **encode** url before sending.

```
ft.upload(imageURI, 
    encodeURI(serverURL + "/upload.php"),
function (e) {
    alert('success');
},function (e) {
    alert("failed");
},options);
```

Comment: Same result with encodeURI.  I see my problem is how FileTransfer is sending the POST data, i.e. no boundary as show in my updated question.  Could it be due to version of Android?

Comment: Android version would not be a problem.In my recent project, there was similar upload functionality required. The desktop web app was able to upload pics easily while uploading from mobile it was sometimes working and sometimes not. my personal android device was not able to upload pic at all, however two other devices- Galaxy & iPhone were able to upload Pic sometimes but not always.So we set up another server in own office to check the functionality &it worked perfectly well.So we shown to client and then their network team did something & then all devices were able to upload Pics easily.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look my sample here, I hope it helps.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
<!– WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 –>
<meta content=
"user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"
name="viewport">
<script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Camera Cordova Plugin</title>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button><br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo
Library</button><br>
<img id="image" src="" style="display:none;width:100%;">
<button onclick="upload();">Upload</button>
</body>
</html>
```

js

```
function upload() {
    var img = document.getElementById('image');
    var imageURI = img.src;
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    var params = new Object();
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, "https://www.example.com/upload.php", win, fail,
        options);
}

function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}
```

php

```
<?php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], '/path/to/file');
```

http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/07/12/upload-image-using-file-transfer-cordova-plugin-for-ios-and-android/

Comment: Where is your capturePhoto() function defined?

Comment: that one came from camera cordova plugin, http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/05/03/tutorial-camera-cordova-plugin-for-ios-and-android/

Comment: I really think it's something with the FileTransfer plugin or settings.  Taking the photo is fine and it's sending the data, just not in the right MIME format

Comment: you can test my source code here, https://github.com/datomnurdin/com.revivalx.cordova.file-transfer

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the boundary yourself adding headers to your `FileUploadOptions`

```
var headers={'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; boundary=+++++'};
options.headers = headers;
```